Flutter Inventory Management: Read from a json assets file, write to a local file and add to a Riverpod managed list of items
I am trying to learn Flutter through implementation of an inventory app. My app currently reads a list of items from a json file, managed by riverpod, this part works. I also read that Flutter does not allow writing to assets, so I wrote an insertItem() method that writes to a local file and also adds the new item to the managed current Items list. Neither of them are being generated, with no errors. I just see 'Item Added' snack bar, Inventory List is same in the inventory list screen and also file is not in the local device file explorer. I will try to briefly add the relevant parts of the code, let me know if wish to see some other parts. Reading from Json assets file part works fine.
@riverpod
class JsonInventoryService extends _$JsonInventoryService {
  late Future<List<Item>> _currentItems;
  late InventoryResult inventoryResult;
@override
  Future<List<Item>> build() {
    return Future.value([Item(id: 0, productName: 'NULL ITEM'),]);
  }

  Future loadItems() async {
    var jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/inventorylist.json');
    inventoryResult =
    InventoryResult.fromJson(jsonDecode(jsonString));
    _currentItems = Future.value(inventoryResultsToItems(inventoryResult));

  }
Future<List<Item>> fetchData() async {
    return _currentItems;
  }

INSERT ITEM METHOD:
 Map<String, dynamic> insertItem(Item item) {
    inventoryResult.results.add(item);
    final jsonmap = inventoryResult.toJson(); //json_serializable automatically handles nested class
    storage.writeFile(jsonmap);
    return jsonmap;
  }

}

Inventory Result is just a model class that has areas for item properties and toJson, fromJson that is being managed by json_serializable.
Storage class:
class Storage {
  Future<String> get _localPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    return directory.path;
  }

  Future<File> get _localFile async {
    final path = await _localPath;
    return File('$path/inventorylist.json');
  }

  Future<File> writeFile(dynamic jsonmap) async {
    final file = await _localFile;
    return file.writeAsString('$jsonmap');
  }
}

ADD NEW ITEM DART FILE:
class AddItemButton extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {

  const AddItemButton({
    required this.image,
    required this.mode,
    required this.storage,
    super.key,
  });

  final Storage storage;
  @override
  ConsumerState createState() => _AddItemButtonState();
}

class _AddItemButtonState extends ConsumerState<AddItemButton> {
  late var inventoryService = ref.watch(serviceProvider);
  late var currentItemList = inventoryService.fetchData();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Item addNewItem({int? barcodeNo, required String productName}) {
      int id = Random().nextInt(100);
      Item newItem =
      Item(id: id, productName: productName, barcodeNo: barcodeNo, isActive: true,);
      inventoryService.insertItem(newItem);
      print("Added $productName!");
      return newItem;
    }

Storage object is being created in main.dart and being passed to relevant screens and classes. Add Item button uses insertItem() function. The screen that shows inventory items uses fetchData() function. Please let me know if needed any more clarifications.
Any suggestions to improve or fix is really appreciated as I have just started last month..
EDIT:
I have edited code as suggestions so now that build() method of the riverpod service provider returns the currentItems list, but I am unable to use this list anywhere on my app, as it throws AsyncValue<List>> cannot be assigned to List or Future type errors in several places where I used the original list with FutureBuilder, or even when I try to use state as a List. What am I missing here?
EDIT 2:
I used async builder with when() expression to access the lists and now everything is working. Leaving all of these just in case someone is newly starting on Riverpod like me.

By this method it will generate  in app directory . go and check in it . For string in external storage you need to give permission .

How is any of this "riverpod"?  Your class-based provider has no build() method, and you never ref.watch the corresponding provider.

@RandalSchwartz I skipped considerable chunks of my app code that seemed too ordinary, but it has those parts. I can edit to include in the question. Please have a look at it now.

See, now I can ask questions like "why does your build not return the actual items rather than a dummy entry?"

Ah I see now, that was just supposed to be a default value if no items found. But I think I need to study Riverpod a bit more to understand better... Thank you for going through my code

Think about Riverpod as composition of providers similar to Flutter's composition of widgets.
You have quite a bit of logic trapped in non-providers/notifiers which is affecting your ability to get "rebuilds".
This is a common fault when using Riverpod for the first time where the the build method is not properly used. It is not good practice to return data from other functions in notifiers, you want to either affect the state or invalidate to cause notifiers/providers to change. You should not be returning data from other functions.
In order to properly get the desired effect, you will need a new notifier that tracks the STATE of the list of Items and handles the Items Modification/Additions. Then we can combine that logic together and observe Riverpod's magic.
In your example, you are have a notifier called JsonInventoryService. Its build method is only return one item always and that is the NULL ITEM. This is the fault point, this needs to watch another provider that is in-charge of the Items. So when the Items Notifier changes, the JsonInventoryService will rebuild because it is watching that notifier.
Here is an approach to how we can change this code so that your usage of ref.watch will properly trigger. I did not compile this code but it should get the idea across.
Original
@riverpod
class JsonInventoryService extends _$JsonInventoryService {
  late Future<List<Item>> _currentItems;
  late InventoryResult inventoryResult;
@override
  Future<List<Item>> build() {
    return Future.value([Item(id: 0, productName: 'NULL ITEM'),]);
  }

  Future loadItems() async {
    var jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/inventorylist.json');
    inventoryResult =
    InventoryResult.fromJson(jsonDecode(jsonString));
    _currentItems = Future.value(inventoryResultsToItems(inventoryResult));

  }
Future<List<Item>> fetchData() async {
    return _currentItems;
  }

Modified
@riverpod
class ItemsService extends _$ItemsService {
    Future<List<Item>> build() async {
        final jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/inventorylist.json');
        final inventoryResult = InventoryResult.fromJson(jsonDecode(jsonString));
        return inventoryResultsToItems(inventoryResult);
    }

    Future<void> addItem(Item item) async {
        //Makes a copy of the existing state list
        final current = List.from(state);
        current.add(item);
        //Updates the state such that it includes the new item
        //Causes a rebuild of anything watching via ref.watch
        state = current;
    }
  }


@riverpod
class JsonInventoryService extends _$JsonInventoryService {
  @override
  Future<List<Item>> build() async {
    final items = await ref.watch(itemsService.future);
    if(items.isEmpty) {
        return [Item(id: 0, productName: 'NULL ITEM'),];
    } else {
        return items;
  }
}

You should now be able to get reactiveness when the additional items are added and your JsonInventoryService should rebuild.

Thank you so much for taking the time to answering my question. I understood the points about build() and also I was not changing the state at all. Now that I have this modified InventoryService, since it returns Items list, instead of doing this >> late var inventoryService = ref.watch(serviceProvider); late var currentItemList = inventoryService.fetchData(); ] should I just do this >> late var currentItemList = ref.watch(serviceProvider); in the relevant screens that uses this list and get rid of fetchData() method altogether?

@Stooges4 Of course, I wanted to make sure you had a good understanding of it all. Riverpod is a powerful tool but has a steep learning curve. ||| Regarding your question, yes you should get rid of "fetchData()" and use "final itemList = ref.watch(serviceProvider);". Make sure to only call "ref.watch(provider)" inside a widget's build or notifier's build method. Otherwise you may run into bugs.

Now I am trying out your answer, and I am getting error: state is AsyncData type, which cannot be assigned to Iterable type. From List.from(state) line. Any ideas?

I will open this question again, as I am getting Async type errors all over my code wherever I try to use this List.

I would have to see more of your code. Is it possible for you to create a sample GitHub project?

I figured out the issue, since Riverpod annotation package made my provider into AsyncNotifierProvider, I just had to use AsyncValue access methods to both use the list in the widgets and also to access state list, such as .when() and .data and .value attributes to make back and forth conventions, so I have just learned about Async types. Thank you so much, really appreciated it!

Of course! Learning is a journey and glad you are advancing. Another method is “ref.listen(provider)” this method lets you have more control than ref.watch and allows you to do imperative actions like “setState, navigation and showing dialogs or what not”.
